# Precedence of operators in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, sqlplus, operator-precedence

**How is**

```
A - B U B - A
```

**parsed in SQL*Plus?**

Is it parsed as

`(A - B) U (B - A)` or as `A - (B U B) - A` ?

I could find [this page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm) using Google, but it doesn't say which has higher precedence, `U` or `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Oracle, all SQL set operators have equal precedence.
See: http://www.nycinformatics.com/sql/sqlsetoperators.htm\
and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58225/ch3all.htm

So, for your question, the order is:

```
(((A - B) U B) - A)
```